# Windows 10 - Prevent external monitor (that is plugged into a thunderbolt dock) from turning off when laptop lid is opened

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, external-display, thunderbolt, docking-station

I typically use my laptop with it plugged into a thunderbolt dock and the lid closed. Sometimes I need to open up the lid so that I can use the webcam. Upon opening the lid the external display that is plugged into the dock turns off and the laptop's internal display activates. I then need to go into the display settings to re-enable the external display and display the internal display.

What I would like is either:

1. for this behavior to stop happening or
2. be able to bind some script to a hotkey sequence to perform the re-enabling and disabling.

As some supporting information, I can tell you that this does not happen with an identical laptop I have that runs Linux.

The laptop and the docks are as follows:

- Thinkpad T490
- ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the 2nd screen is part of your setup in display settings when the lid is open. If so it may go black for a moment but it shouldn't powerdown. Failing that I would check the power saving settings of your monitor and confirm it's not just going to sleep the moment it doesn't receive a signal.

Comment: When I check the display settings after opening the lid, I see that the external display is recognized but the configuration has been changed to only use the laptops internal display. I have to then manually change it to only show on the external display again. I've checked the settings on my external display, but I can't find anything that would be at all related.